# .NET Assembly Version

Tags: .net, assemblies, version

The scenario is as follows. Developers compile the projects and deploy assemblies to production. eg, deployment contains 10 assemblies. Out of 10, they actually change the source code only in 5 assemblies and they recompile other 5 assemblies without changing the source code. Before deployment, I want to trace which assemblies are actually changing and which are just recompiling. I can add version info or something in the project or build process. I can also access assemblies of previous build. But this process must be automated.
Thanks,
Ant.

Comment: I don't understandm, If you don't change anything in the source then assembly is not changed, please clarify what do you mean by "file is changed"

Comment: Are you doing this just to check for yourself, or are you trying to do it programmatically?

Comment: Because of confusion, I rewrite my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can convert both (previous and current) assemblies pdbs to xml (because pdb files for just recompiled source will differ) and binary (or ascii) compare them. If source was not changed then xml files will be the same.

[Converting a managed PDB into a XML file.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160223205849/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/jmstall/archive/2005/08/25/pdb2xml.aspx)

Using this (not ideal, but anyway) approach you can fully automate changed source detection.

Comment: It is difficult to find Pdb2Xml in above link. Here is direct download link for MdbgSample (contains Pdb2Xml Utility):http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/2/f/12f5dde6-695d-4003-a451-739ab3be6098/mdbgSample21.EXE